# How to run small piece of code in Async way in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to PHP and using laravel in my project.

I have a service which is called from front end via controller.

**Flow is:**
Admin creates a notification-> notification is saved in database -> send mobile notification -> success

**I want to change it to:**
Admin creates a notification-> notification is saved in database -> aync (send mobile notification) -> success

without waiting for system to send notification (which can take time, since it's in 100s for different mobile devices)

What is simplest piece of code can be written to handle it? (In java we intial a new thread and execution can take place - to run in background)

Comment: Laravel Queues is what you are looking for. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Answer (score 0):

Use the job and supervisor service together:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

If you need more help, reply to me.